# Canvas with negative z-index issue on scroll in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, canvas, z-index

## Description

There is an issue with canvas negative z-index. Basically, when there is 2 elements in fixed position, one being a block element and the other being the canvas, and the `z-index` of the canvas is negative, it will scroll over the second one no matter what's its `z-index`.

**This bug only occur on Chrome: Mac and PC.**

## Code sample

Here's an HTML sample (reduced fo the question) :

```
<ul>
    <li><span>test1</span></li>
    <li><span>test1</span></li>
    <li><span>test1</span></li>
</ul>

<div>
    <canvas />
</div>
```

And the CSS

```
html,body{
    height : 150%;
}

ul {
    position : fixed;
    z-index : -1;
    top : 0;
    left : 0;
    width : 100%;
    margin : 0;
    padding : 0;
    overflow : auto;

    li {
        float : left;
        width : 33%;
        height : 100px;
        background : red;
        position : relative;
        list-style: none;

        span{
            display:block;
            position : relative;
        }
    }
}
div {
    position : fixed;
    z-index : -2;
    top : 0;
    left : 0;

    canvas{
        opacity : 0.5
    }
}
```

*I am omitting the JavaScript  since i'm sure it is not the problem.*

You can see the bug in action in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3a66445w/1/)

## Some tries that kinda solved the issue, but that I cannot use...

After trying multiple things, here what solved the current issue but caused trouble on other points:

- **Setting `overflow:visible` to the `ul`;**

  - Somehow, that fix the problem, but I can't use that since I'm using `$.fn.slideDown()` on it. During the animation, jQuery set the `overflow` to `hidden`, making the bug visible when animating.
- **Changing the `position:relative` of the `li` and `span` to something else;**

  - That does work too, probably the *best* solution... if you don't have absolute element inside. Which is the case for me. I can't use that fix as well.
- **Using only negative `z-index` everywhere (`-2` on `canvas`, `-1` on `ul`);**

  - That does work as well, but it mess everything on IOS (and maybe other devices, didn't test everything).
- **Not using negative `z-index`;**

  - That would be the best, but iOS doesn't likes it. When scrolling, unpainted element will appear under the canvas until the scroll finish. This is an undesirable behaviour.

Comment: In my case putting z-index: -1 on the body solved the scrolling issue of a div with z-index: -1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This seems to be a Chromium/webkit (or blink) bug, and this fixes it, meeting all your criteria and no changes needed on the `HTML` structure or the rest of the styles:

```
ul {
    /* rest of the styles */
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
```

**Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/3a66445w/2/

Comment: I can't belive it worked! You're a life saver, thank you very much!

Comment: I'm so amazed that I actually found an answer to this totally weird problem. I didn't have a negative z-index, but still had the issue, though, and this seems to have fixed it

Comment: you honestly deserve all the points in the world for solving this issue. thankyou.